# MySQL ignore index even with use index or force index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Here I'll add part of my query because it's sensitive information and I will use not real names:

```
SELECT
  `entity`.`id`,
  `entity`.`requirements`,
  `entity`.`description`,
  `entity`.`status`,
  `entity_videos`.`length`,
  `entity_videos`.`quality`,
  `states`.`name`,
  `uploads`.`id`,
  `uploads`.`name`
    FROM  `entity`
    LEFT JOIN  `states`  ON `states`.`id` = `entity`.`state_id`
    INNER JOIN  `uploads` FORCE INDEX (`uploadable_id_index`)
       ON  `uploads`.`uploadable_type` = 'Entity'
      AND  `uploads`.`category` = 'Icon'
      AND  (`uploads`.`uploadable_id` = `entity`.`id`
              OR  `uploads`.`uploadable_id` = `entity`.`parent_entity_for_icon`
           )
    INNER JOIN  `entity_videos` FORCE INDEX (entity_videos_entity_id_index)
       ON `entity_videos`.`entity_id` = `entity`.`id`
    WHERE  `entity`.`status` = 'active'
```

The issue is that Mysql optimizer do not want to use `uploadable_id_index` index. Part of explain:

[image: part of explain querye]

As I know `FORCE INDEX`is force optimizer to use index except for situation that optimizer can't use the index. What should I do to force that index and do not make a full scan of the table? 
I tried to remove `entity_videos_entity_id_index` also I tried to add `uploads` table information to where clause, but nothing works for me. Any ideas? Thank you very much for any help

**Updated:**

With help of @Barmar and @PaulSpiegel I found that issue is in `(uploads.uploadable_id = entity.id OR uploads.uploadable_id = entity.parent_entity_for_icon)`. And playing with query for some time I found that best solution in my case is:

```
 SELECT
  `entity`.`id`,
  `entity`.`requirements`,
  `entity`.`description`,
  `entity`.`status`,
  `entity_videos`.`length`,
  `entity_videos`.`quality`,
  `states`.`name`,
  `icon`.`id`,
  `icon`.`name`,
  `parent_offer_icon`.`id`,
  `parent_offer_icon`.`name`
    FROM  `entity`
    LEFT JOIN  `states`  ON `states`.`id` = `entity`.`state_id`
    LEFT JOIN  `uploads` as `icon` FORCE INDEX (`uploadable_id_index`)
       ON  `icon`.`uploadable_type` = 'Entity'
      AND  `icon`.`category` = 'Icon'
      AND  `icon`.`uploadable_id` = `entity`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN  `uploads` as `parent_offer_icon` FORCE INDEX (`uploadable_id_index`)
       ON  `parent_offer_icon`.`uploadable_type` = 'Entity'
      AND  `parent_offer_icon`.`category` = 'Icon'
      AND  `parent_offer_icon`.`uploadable_id` = `entity`.`parent_entity_for_icon`
    INNER JOIN  `entity_videos` FORCE INDEX (entity_videos_entity_id_index)
       ON  `entity_videos`.`entity_id` = `entity`.`id`
    WHERE  `entity`.`status` = 'active'
      AND  (parent_offer_icon.id IS NOT NULL
              OR  icon.id IS NOT NULL )
```

I'm still open for other suggestions :)

Comment: The `OR` condition might be the problem. Try using `uploadable_id IN (entity.id, entity.parent_entity_for_icon)`

Comment: @Barmar thanks for a proposal but it's also not working. And I forgot, a few days ago when there were much fewer records in DB optimizer select that index, maybe it's really now much faster to make a full scan instead of using an index?

Comment: Usually indexes are more useful when the table gets bigger. But maybe the cardinality of that index is too low. Use `SHOW INDEX FROM uploads;` to see.

Comment: @Barmar but you were right, issue is in `(uploads.uploadable_id = entity.id OR uploads.uploadable_id = entity.parent_entity_for_icon` section. When I'm removing  `uploads.uploadable_id = entity.parent_entity_for_icon` it start working. But `IN` solution you proposed is not help

Comment: It just might not be able to use an index when it needs to compare with multiple columns in the other table.

Comment: can be... will look into another way. Thank you!

Comment: Try splitting into two queries and combining with `UNION`.

Comment: Please read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) (search for "Range checked for each record"). If I understand it correctly, it doesn't mean that no index is used, but that the index is chosen at runtime ("for each record"). But I'm not sure :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel hm interesting, so maybe it's not so bad :)

Comment: I would benchmark it on a big data set and compare the runtime with a UNION (ALL) query.

Comment: Also try a composite index on `(uploadable_type, category, uploadable_id)`.

Comment: working on `UNION` as you guys suggested. And about composite index, I have try it already and  optimizer does not use it also

Comment: Last one: Depending on your data (logic) you might want to change the condition to `uploadable_id = COALESCE(entity.id, entity.parent_entity_for_icon)`.

Comment: I change that `INNER JOIN` on two `LEFT JONS` and in where clause I use conditions like `(parent_offer_icon.id IS NOT NULL OR icon.id IS NOT NULL)`. In my case, it shows me best result. Thank you guys, I would not solve it without you :)

Comment: Turning `OR` into two `LEFT JOINs` is an interesting trick.  I wonder whether it is better than turning it into `UNION`.  (See my answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by turning the pesky `OR` into `UNION`:

```
( SELECT  e.id AS eid,
          u.id AS uid,
          u.name AS uname
    FROM `uploads` AS u 
    INNER JOIN  `entity` AS e
       ON  u.`uploadable_id` = e.`id`
    WHERE  u.`uploadable_type` = 'Entity'
      AND  u.`category` = 'Icon'
      AND  e.status = 'active'
) UNION DISTINCT
( SELECT  e.id AS eid,
          u.id AS uid,
          u.name AS uname
    FROM `uploads` AS u 
    INNER JOIN   `entity` AS e
       ON  u.`uploadable_id` = e.`parent_entity_for_icon` 
    WHERE  u.`uploadable_type` = 'Entity'
      AND  u.`category` = 'Icon'
      AND  e.status = 'active'
)
```

That will need some of these indexes:

```
uploads:  INDEX(uploadable_type, category, uploadable_id, id, name)
entity:   INDEX(parent_entity_for_icon, status, id)
```

(I assume `entity` has `PRIMARY KEY(id)`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` so I don't have to guess.)  If there are problems with such a long index, let me know; I can probably provide a workaround.

By turning the `OR` into a `UNION`, different indexes can be used for each part.  With `OR`, the Optimizer usually punts and does something inefficient.

Please verify that the query above runs fast and produces reasonable output.  Then...

```
SELECT  e.`id`, e.`requirements`, e.`description`, e.`status`,
        ev.`length`, ev.`quality`,
        s.`name`,
        uid, uname
    FROM ( the-query-above ) AS i
    JOIN `entity` AS e  ON e.id = i.eid
    LEFT JOIN  `states` AS s  ON s.`id` = e.`state_id`
    INNER JOIN  `entity_videos` AS ev  ON ev.`entity_id` = i.eid
```

Other than `PRIMARY KEY(id)` on each table, you will need

```
entity_videos:  INDEX(entity_id)  -- good, or
entity_videos:  INDEX(entity_id, length, quality)  -- better ("covering")
```

Don't use `FORCE INDEX`.

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Comment: Thank you for proposal, I believe it's can be the best one, but in my case, it takes a pretty same amount of time to execute the query with your and my solution, but your solution is harder to implement using ORM.  I saw your profile and it looks like you are an expert in MySQL :). Maybe you will be interested to see the full query and tables structure and we can continue a conversation in private (maybe through email or so)?  Anyway, thank you!!!

Comment: Yeah, ORMs tend to get in the way of performance.  mysql at rjweb dot org .  Can you start by timing the `UNION` and the equivalent `OR` _with_ the indexes suggested.